# How to change staging URL?

Tags: c#, azure

I deployed my MVC application on windows azure staging environment. Now because of some reason i want to change my staging URL. Can anybody please guid me, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change a staging url. The only thing you can do is create a CNAME for it and have something like: **stagingapp.mycompany.com**.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this guide helps you.[Azure Staging](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/cloud-computing2/windows-azure-staging-server-140381).